# Laravel 5.2 + Authorize user to perform action

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

Consider below scenario.

- There are 2 users who registered with the system.
- If user 1 is logged in and tries to update User 2's profile. It should not be allowed.

I have tried it using Request class.

```
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class ProfileRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        $routeUser  = $this->route('userId');
        if($routeUser->id == Auth::user()->id){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            abort(403);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** It displays form with all information. It only blocks user when tries to update the info. How to block a user so that he/she cannot even view the form with data??

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel ACL to manage the role wise user access.  By using role wise access only authorized user can access his/her account and do some stuff.

[Laravel ACL documentation](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl)